How to pick the next month's value?
Want to know how to select the row value based on month header using power query?
I have few columns in excel dataset which is loaded and transformed in Power Query. In the below table the months keep changing and new months will be getting added. I have below columns :



ID
Name
Category
Dec
Jan
Feb




001
per 1
active
100
100
100


002
per 2
inactive
100
100
100


003
per 3
inactive
0
0
0



I want to filter out persons with 'inactive' category and who are having 100 in next month(Current month +1). In the above it should pick person with 002 ID as he is 'inactive' and still has 100 in Jan month.
please help as it looks easy but not able to get the right logic to use.

how many month's data do you have ? what if you have more than one year data and you have two columns of Jan. How to Identify which column is this year and which column is for last year?

Thanks for the response. It will be maximum of 6 months of data at any given point. Not more than that.

here is a workaround for you.
I will create a month table.


select the first three columns and unpivot other tables


merge two tables and bring monthnum to the main table




add a new column to show next month's num
if Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()) = 12 then 1 else +1




add a new column to mark the rows that we need
=if [Next Month]=[monthnum] and [Category]="inactive" and [Value] <>0  then "y" else "n"




filter and select the value is "y" and delete created columns


below is the completed M coding
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjAwVNJRKkgtUgDRicklmWWpQIahgQEKGasDUmoEVQqiM/MIKDaGKjZGVWwAx7GxAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, Name = _t, Category = _t, Dec = _t, Jan = _t, Feb = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Category", type text}, {"Dec", Int64.Type}, {"Jan", Int64.Type}, {"Feb", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Name", "Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute"}, month, {"month"}, "month", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded month" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "month", {"monthnum"}, {"monthnum"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded month", "Next Month", each if Date.Month(DateTime.LocalNow()) = 12 then 1 else +1),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", each if [Next Month]=[monthnum] and [Category]="inactive" and [Value] <>0  then "y" else "n"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Custom] = "y")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"monthnum", "Next Month", "Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"


Your data is already in a report format, with month as a reporting category across the columns.
Consider unpivoting the data with Power Query. It's a standard command on the ribbon in the Power Query Editor. Once unpivoted, you will have a flat table with the columns, ID, Name, Category, Month and Value. You can then easily build this exact matrix in a Power BI visual, and you can use filters/slicers to show only the desired months columns.

Thanks for the response. I am automating the whole process of filtering so I want the power query to run on new dataset every month and show me the results by just refreshing the data.

That's a statement. Do you have a follow-up question? Power Query is built to refresh with new data.

This assumes the column you want to check is always one column to the right of the column name you provide as CurrentMonth.  So looking for "Dec" in this case will check the next column over which happens to be "Jan"
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
CurrentMonth="Dec",
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Category]="inactive" and Record.FieldValues(_){List.PositionOf(Table.ColumnNames(Source),CurrentMonth)+1}=100)
in #"Filtered Rows"


If that's not your logic you are going to have to use date math to decide the column name to check and then look for that in the {} portion

Thanks for the response. Is there any way where I can get current month without hardcoding because next month the current month will be Jan and this code may not work.

How do I know what your current month is, since you didn't explain your request well at all.  Are you storing the current month name in a cell with a range name? If so then use CurrentMonth=Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="rangenamehere"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],

Current month will be Dec for now. Next month the current month will be Jan and so on. Not storing current month anywhere but it should take the calendar month only.

you didn't provide an appropriate sample or description how to determine current month, so I'll leave it for you to figure out
